# Data Model in Swift with multiple variables based on each other

Tags: ios, swift, data-modeling

I am currently stuck on a situation where I need to create a data model that will be used in a UITableView for both adding posts and retrieving them (read: showing them in a feed). Allow me to explain:

I want to create a standard data model for a post, which contains a title, a body and tags. I use a struct for this.

```
struct Post {
    var Title: String
    var Body: String
    var Tags: [String]
}
```

This works great. I can re-use this to create multiple posts simultaneously in a `UITableView` which is exactly what I want. However, the problem occurs now when I want to improve my system. I want to allow users to add attachments, whether they are images or videos (let's keep it at those two for this example and leave out text documents, pdfs, ...). My `UITableView` is set up in a way where every section is a post and every row is an item of that post. The title is defined in a `UITextField` in the section header and the tags are defined in the footer of the section. The body is a row. I now want to allow users to add a row to add whatever they want: plain text (a "body" row), but also image(s) or video(s). I will create three buttons: Add Text, Add Image and Add Video.

How can I improve my data model so that it can hold all this information? Should I, for example, add one variable "Attachments" for all types (image and video), or should I create separate optional variables like this:

```
struct Post {
    var postTitle: String
    var postBody: String
    var postTags: [String]
    var postImages: [AttachmentImage]
    var postVideos: [AttachmentVideo]
}

struct AttachmentImage {
    var imageTitle: String
    var imageReference: String
    var imageSize: Int
}

struct AttachmentVideo {
    var videoTitle: String
    var videoReference: String
    var videoSize: Int
    var videoThumbnail: String
}
```

This seems possible, but I would like to achieve in a certain way that I can change the variables based on another variable. Ideally I would have something like:

```
enum PostTypes {
    case Text, Image, Video
}

struct Post {
    var postTitle: String
    var postBody: String
    var postTags: [String]
    var postType: PostTypes
}
```

And then, if the type is Text, I want to keep it as-is, but if the type is Image, I want to add imageTitle, imageReference and imageSize, and the same for Video. Is there a way to achieve this, or should I go with the optionals?

Comment: Just to clarify more, single post can have multiple types or only one type ( Text or Image or Video)?

Comment: It can be more. You should think of it as a post on Facebook, where a user can, for example, upload 2 images, 1 video and a text to clarify what they upload. It will then be shown as a carousel in the feed.

Answer (score 0):

First as first: If you have model named `Post` you don't have to name its properties like `postTitle`, `postBody`, etc. ... `title` or `body` is enough.

---

You can define protocol for your structs and then you can add generic constraint for your `Post` struct

```
protocol Attachment {
    var title: String { get set }
    var reference: String { get set }
    var size: Int { get set }
}

struct Post<T: Attachment> {
    var title: String
    var body: String
    var tags: [String]
    var attachments: [T]
}

struct AttachmentImage: Attachment {
    var title: String
    var reference: String
    var size: Int
}

struct AttachmentVideo: Attachment {
    var title: String
    var reference: String
    var size: Int
    var thumbnail: String
}
```

---

Example usage:

```
let post = Post(title: "", body: "", tags: [], attachments: [AttachmentImage(title: "", reference: "", size: 1)])
post.attachments /* type: [AttachmentImage] */

let post = Post(title: "", body: "", tags: [], attachments: [AttachmentVideo(title: "", reference: "", size: 1, thumbnail: "")])
post.attachments /* type: [AttachmentVideo] */
```